# How to create python/numpy array from text file?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I have a white-space separated list of integers in the following format in a text file.

```
1 2 3 4 ...#First row can have any number of entries
3 5 6 1 6 7 8 9 ...#The next row can have a different number of entries
#More such rows different number of entries in each row
```

How do I create a python list from this file? The output that I am looking for is a 1D array with all the numbers in a single list like [1,2,3,4,...,3,5,6,1,6,7,8,9,...]. Any numpy based options are also welcome. Thanks for any help and suggestions.

Comment: What have you tried? This is a basic task. Please show us the code you've come up with that you're having trouble with. If you don't have that, please do some research then come back. SO is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 0):

The following function should do the trick:

```
def file_2_int_list (file_path):
    retval = []
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            for num in line.split(' '):
                retval.append(int(num))
return retval
```

This function gets a path to a file, iterates over the text line by line, splitting each line into a list (using whitespace as a delimiter), and returns a list of all values (converted to integers).

The same can be accomplished with less lines of code using lambda expressions, but I kept it simple seeing as you appear to be a beginner.